# module 'modules.win.win' has no attribute 'listen' What can I do?

Tags: python

I need a little bit of help with this project. I was going to make a Python project about the game PONG. I've followed a tutorial that explained how to write it and it worked. Today I wanted to improve it because, the guy who made the tutorial, wrote everything into a single .py file which I did find quite overwhelming. I've separated every component of the code (objects and functions) into little python modules so that I can use them in the main code and see if something was wrong. And it was. I've decided to make first a debug and then, if nothing went wrong, run the actual program. Now I'm stuck with this error from VS Code :

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "g:\pong\main2.py", line 9, in <module> win.listen() AttributeError: module 'modules.win.win' has no attribute 'listen'`

How can I fix this?

I'll attach the GitHub link of my project:
https://github.com/fenixthebuilder/pong-version-2

Comment: `win` should probably be an instance of the `modules.win.win.win` class, not the `modules.win.win` module.

Comment: I don't know how to do it since I am a novice in programming. There is some guide I can follow?